# RUN iLogic rule on drawing (old C360_OnPublish)

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

when we used configurator 360 we could start a rule on the Inventor Drawing (idw) simply by calling it "C360_OnPublish".
Now with Forge it doesn't work anymore.

Run Rule is essential to be able to do a quick scaling of the view after a configuration update the drawing, and before the PDF is published.

Is there a quick method that allows you to do the same thing?
we also tried to insert the rule in the Inventor EventTriggers ('Before save document' or 'Drawing view change') but without success.

thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can run directly iLogic macro from your FDA AppBundle. You need to obtain the iLogic Addin first and then start a method from this Addin.

```
ApplicationAddIn iLogicAddIn = inventorApplication.ApplicationAddIns.ItemById["{3BDD8D79-2179-4B11-8A5A-257B1C0263AC}"];
dynamic iLogicAutomation = iLogicAddIn.Automation;
iLogicAutomation.RunRule(doc, "Your_iLogic_script");
```

Another option is to run the iLogic script directly from your activity without the AppBundle, but there are some caveats related to that, mainly long operations without any output and with missing heart beating can cause the processing timeouts. This video demonstrates how to do that:
https://youtu.be/kA82e_XcMrY?t=100

Answer (score 0):

Configurator 360 is available in Design Automation. You would need to trigger the rule yourself using Inventor API, depending on your code logic.